# fetch data from two different tables on same textbox changed event

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I want to fetch some data from two different tables `PRO` and `OPN_STK` , in some controls like textboxs and datagridview . when i am selecting data from one table i.e. `PRO` ,the code is working perfect but when i applied same code just next to it , in same event for fetching data from another table i.e. `OPN_STK` it throws exception "`object refrence not set to an instance of object`" . I tried to know about the problem but now I'm blank , this is what I did ,

```
private void comboProname_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
             dataGridView3.Rows.Clear();
             dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
             //if (get == false)     //in case when i need to apply condition which I dont prefer
             {
                 string _sql = "select DISTINCT P_batchno,P_sh from PRO where P_name='" + comboProname.Text + "'";
                 if (comboBthNo.Text != "")
                     _sql += " AND P_batchno='" + comboBthNo.Text + "' ";
                 if (SampleToggle)
                     _sql += " AND IsSample='true' ";
                 else
                     _sql += " AND IsSample='false' ";

                 DataTable dt = DataBase.getDataTable(_sql);

                 foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                 {
                     if (comboBthNo.Text == "")
                     {
                         dataGridView3.Visible = true;
                         int i = 0;
                         dataGridView3.Rows.Insert(i);
                         dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dr["P_batchno"].ToString();
                         dataGridView3.Focus();
                     }
                     sh = dr["P_sh"].ToString();
                 }
             }
             //else if (get == true)   // opnstk
             {
                 string _sql = "select DISTINCT P_batchno,P_sh from OPN_STK where P_name='" + comboProname.Text + "'";
                 if (comboBthNo.Text != "")
                     _sql += " AND P_batchno='" + comboBthNo.Text + "' ";
                 if (SampleToggle)
                     _sql += " AND IsSample='true' ";
                 else
                     _sql += " AND IsSample='false' ";

                 DataTable dt = DataBase.getDataTable(_sql);

                 foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                 {
                     if (comboBthNo.Text == "")
                     {
                         dataGridView3.Visible = true;
                         int i = 0;
                         dataGridView3.Rows.Insert(i);
                         dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dr["P_batchno"].ToString();
                         dataGridView3.Focus();
                     }
                     sh = dr["P_sh"].ToString();
                 }
             }                
             getdata();
        }

        private void comboBthNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView3.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
           // if (get == false)
            {
                string _sql = "SELECT DISTINCT P_name,P_pack,P_comp,P_expdate,P_rate,P_mrp from PRO where P_batchno='" + comboBthNo.Text + "'";
                if (comboProname.Text != "")
                    _sql += " AND P_name='" + comboProname.Text + "'";
                if (SampleToggle)
                    _sql += " AND IsSample='true' ";
                else
                    _sql += " AND IsSample='false' ";

                DataTable dt = DataBase.getDataTable(_sql);

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if (comboProname.Text == "")
                    {
                        dataGridView2.Visible = true;
                        int i = 0;
                        dataGridView2.Rows.Insert(i);
                        dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dr["P_name"].ToString();
                        dataGridView2.Focus();
                    }
                    tbMrp.Text = (dr["P_mrp"].ToString());
                    dateTimePicker2.Text = (dr["P_expdate"].ToString());
                }
            }
           // else if (get == true)   ///// opn stk ///////
            {
                string _sql = "SELECT DISTINCT P_name,P_pack,P_comp,P_expdate,P_rate,P_mrp from OPN_STK where P_batchno='" + comboBthNo.Text + "'";
                if (comboProname.Text != "")
                    _sql += " AND P_name='" + comboProname.Text + "'";
                if (SampleToggle)
                    _sql += " AND IsSample='true' ";
                else
                    _sql += " AND IsSample='false' ";

                DataTable dt = DataBase.getDataTable(_sql);

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)  // I get exception here only on dt
                {
                    if (comboProname.Text == "")
                    {
                        dataGridView2.Visible = true;
                        int i = 0;
                        dataGridView2.Rows.Insert(i);
                        dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dr["P_name"].ToString();
                        dataGridView2.Focus();
                    }
                    tbMrp.Text = (dr["P_mrp"].ToString());
                    dateTimePicker2.Text = (dr["P_expdate"].ToString());
                }
            }
            getdata();
        }
```

i would appriciate any help ,thanks in advance .

Comment: Good question I was looking for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint in your code, debug and check that OPN_STK is not null. If it is null that would be your problem.

Comment: When it breaks is comboBthNo.Text null?